# Is it bad if I have a lot of options in my model choice field?

Tags: django

I created `cities.py` file which contains all cities of my country (it's 20 kb of data) in list `CITY_CHOICES`. I have a model with city row, I imported `CITY_CHOICES` and set it as choices for this row:

```
city = models.CharField(max_length=63, choices=CITIES_CHOICES, blank=False, null=True)
```

Is it too much? Will I experience performance issues? Sorry, if it's a dumb question.

By the way I use MySQL.

Comment: Typically if you can have an arbitrary amount of options, it is better to use a `ForeignKey` to a `City` model. This makes it also easy to create a new option, or rename/remove an existing one.

Comment: I would go for having a separate model to store the cities data (Some cities might change names, or new ones may come up so cities are not really fixed)

Comment: Thank you! But how do I do it? I guess, I should run `for` loop through cities list and create an entry for every city?

Comment: @Daniil: you can work with a data migration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/ to create data in the database for a migration.

Comment: @Daniil: typically you work with `.bulk_create` to create a large number of records efficiently: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this data is not completely static: eventually cities will be merged into larger ones, cities will be renamed, etc.

You are also restricting the modeling that two different cities have a different name, but that is not per se the case, in many countries, multiple villages have the same name, and two cities are then different by the province, zip code, etc.

A city is also more than its name: you might want to group cities by country, add GPS coordinates, translations in different languages, etc.

These are all reasons to define a `City` model, and use a `ForeignKey` from your model to that city. This also will typically make the database more compact, since you now use an `INT` field instead of a `VAR CHAR`.

I thus would advise to work with something like:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: I did it. But now, when I try to create new entry in `OtherModel`, in my template, in choices field i get options like `Cities object(1)`, `Cities object(2)`, `Cities object(N)`. How do I fix it?

Comment: @Daniil: you can override the `__str__` method to specify how to present a `City` object as text.

Comment: But still, would not it be a huge performance flaw if i let it be choice field? Because I have to rewrite a lot of code to make frontend work with new db design and some things in frontend are even tricky to code

Comment: @Daniil: it makes the database smaller, because you deduplicate data, and typically only fetch the city data if needed, for example through [**`.select_realted(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). Usually it is better to keep databases small, and do filtering, for example on the name of the city on the city table, and then filter through an indexing structure the `OtherModel` with that.

Comment: @Daniil: see also *database normalisation forms*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization